# javascript setMonth() - setting a month to date2 from date1. Why also date1 change?

Tags: javascript, date

I know, title isn't probably clear, but I have this code:

```js
var date1=new Date();
alert(date1);
var date2=date1;
alert(date2);
date2.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 6);
alert(date1+" - "+date2);
```

Why date1 change? I think date1 should remain the current date and date2 six months later ...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Comment: You are modifying same object from different reference. Is any language does what you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the variables are pointing to same date object. You can do this instead

```
var date1=new Date();
alert(date1);
var date2=new Date(date1.valueOf());
alert(date2);
date2.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 6);
alert(date1+" - "+date2);
```

In this approach, I am creating new object using values of existing one. Now there are two objects being point by different variables.

While you had assigned same object to both variables.

Comment: The Date can be copied as `var date2=new Date(date1)`. To accommodate ancient IE and dates from year 0 to 99, use `var date2=new Date(+date1)` (which still works everywhere, even in not old IE). ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Dates are objects in JavaScript. When you set `date2=date1`, both `date1` and `date2` will reference the same object. Since they are both references to the same date object, the object may be updated or inspected using either.

Comment: ...to create a copy: `date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());`

Comment: Thanks so much... and also to you T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Because date2 gets the reference to date1, not value.